# Nested divs with 'display: table-row-group' not laying out properly

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-tables

I'm building out a hierarchical (recursive) table using Angular. Unfortunately angular's directives are part of the HTML DOM and combined with recursion I end up with nested table elements. I am trying to use CSS table layout rather than the classic `<table>` elements.

Using table elements everything lays out okay:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="cell">one</div>
    <td class="cell">two</div>
    <td class="cell">three</div>
</tr>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td>two</td>
            <td>three</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But if I try to do the same things using CSS the layout gets screwed up:

```
<style>
    .table {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }

    .row {
        display: table-row;
    }

    .cell {
        display: table-cell
    }

    .nolayout {
        display: table-row-group
    }
</style>
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">one</div>
    <div class="cell">two</div>
    <div class="cell">three</div>
    </div>
   <div class="nolayout">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">one</div>
        <div class="cell">two</div>
        <div class="cell">three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="nolayout">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">one</div>
        <div class="cell">two</div>
        <div class="cell">three</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle showing the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/LjyLz2Le/7/

Comment: Your fiddle does not match your code - the `display: table-row-group` has been swapped out for `display: inline`, and there are significant differences in the markup.

Comment: I noticed you have a tbody as a child of another tbody. That's not going to work - what you end up having is two consecutive tbody elements (one empty), and an orphaned </tbody> end tag. A row group may only contain rows, not other row groups.

Comment: Sorry the fiddle was changed around. I updated it to match and show the problem at hand.

Comment: And the point of this question is to have some sort of nested structure. I am building our a tree grid (like file browsing) which requires a hierarchical recursive structure.

Answer (score 0):

please change

```
.nolayout {
        display: table-row-group
    }
```

to

```
 .nolayout div {
        display: table-row-group
    }
```

Because the `nolayout` class assign only for the main `div`, does not sub `div`.  you need  assign `table-row-group` for your cell `div`

### [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LjyLz2Le/1/)

Comment: That just converts every inner div to a table-row-group, resulting in a big bunch of row groups each containing one row. Pretty sure that just messes things up even more.